# AcquireTokenSilentAsync not working

Tags: access-token, azure-ad-graph-api

I have the following setup:

```
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
string redirectUri = Url.Action("Authorize", "Planner", null, Request.Url.Scheme);

Uri authUri = authContext.GetAuthorizationRequestURL("https://graph.microsoft.com/", SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                                                      new Uri(redirectUri), UserIdentifier.AnyUser, null);
// Redirect the browser to the Azure signin page
return Redirect(authUri.ToString());
```

This takes you to:

```
// Get the 'code' parameter from the Azure redirect
string authCode = Request.Params["code"];

// The same url we specified in the auth code request
string redirectUri = Url.Action("Authorize", "Planner", null, Request.Url.Scheme);

// Use client ID and secret to establish app identity
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret);

//FileTokenCache at specific location
TokenCache fileTokenCache = new FilesBasedAdalV3TokenCache("C:\\temp\\justin.bin");
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.AzureADAuthorityTenantID, fileTokenCache);

AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
try
{
     // Get the token silently first
     authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.O365UnifiedResource, credential, UserIdentifier.AnyUser);   
}
catch (AdalException ex)
{
     authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.AzureADAuthority, fileTokenCache);

     authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(authCode, new Uri(redirectUri), credential, SettingsHelper.O365UnifiedResource);

}
```

The token is successfully saved in the file and it seems that it is also being successfully retrieved. However the silent token acquisition still gives an exception to get token first using the non silent function. What am I missing please?

Note that O365UnifiedResource is set to https://graph.microsoft.com/

Answer (score 0):

solved this by using

```
new UserIdentifier("<email address used to login microsoft apps>", UserIdentifierType.RequiredDisplayableId)
```

instead of

```
UserIdentifier.AnyUser
```

and fixed the client ID to be the APP ID as specified in the registration of the app